# Mongoose append additional properties to the results based on conditional checks

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

i want to add additional properties to the result document of a mongoose query. i have a Post Model, inside the post model i have added favourites which contains reference to the users who favourited the post, i want to get whether the user has favourited the post and the total number of favourites the post has

Post Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate-v2');
var aggregatePaginate = require('mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2');

const postSchema = Schema({
    title: String,
    favourites: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }],
    description: String
});
var Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate));
Post.prototype.hasLiked = function (uid) {
    return this.favourites.indexOf(uid) > -1
}
Post.prototype.totalLikes = function () {
    return this.favourites.length;
}
module.exports = Post;
```

Controller

```
  Post.paginate(query,
    options,
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.json({
          error: err,
          status: 501,
          message: "Unable to get data"
        });
      } else {
        let isFavourite = result.hasLiked(res.locals.user.uid)
        let favouriteLength = result.totalLikes()
        console.log(isFavourite)
        console.log(favouriteLength)
        res.json({
          status: 200,
          data: result
        });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Im facing the following error while running the above code

```
TypeError: result.hasLiked is not a function
```

Is this an efficient solution, if not please suggest any alternate solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Post.paginate` doesn't return a promise fulfilled with an instance of `Post`.

Following the documentation ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate-v2 ), you will receive your post in `result.docs`. Loop on it and you can use your getters.